# How to bind CustomControl DataTrigger to viewmodel DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

Using MVVM light, I have a control template for a custom control. There are multiple instances of this control. The style is set in Generic.xaml.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type tgvw:TimeSlotRect}">

    <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding TimeSlotRectViewModel, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type tgvw:TimeSlotRect}">

                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Name="TimeSlotBorder"
                        BorderBrush="#A5BFE1"
                        BorderThickness="0,0.5,0,0.5" Height="30">
                    <Rectangle Fill="Beige" Name="Rect">

                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseDownCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                    </Rectangle>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsSelected}" Value="True" >
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black" TargetName="Rect"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The idea is that the mouse button click fires a command in the viewmodel that sets it's *IsSelected* property to *true* and then the rectangle should pick that up and change it's fill to black - but it doesn't seem to work.

If I bind the DataTrigger to the viewmodel like this:

```
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TimeSlotRectViewModel.IsSelected, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Value="True" >
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black" TargetName="Rect"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

It fires and every control changes to black. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First of all you should write your custom control independent of your ViewModel.

Comment: The CustomControl is behaving as a view - it won't be reused at all. How would you track the IsSelected property to keep it independent? A DP?

Comment: Yes you can create a DP IsSelected and bind to your viewmode.